# using spark to Access hbase columns with space within

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I'm trying to read a HBASE table using spark.

This piece of code works fine :

```py
columns_mapping = """
    id string :key,
    Campagne string data:Campagne
"""

df = spark.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").option(
    "hbase.table",
    tablename,
).option(
    "hbase.columns.mapping",
    columns_mapping,
).option(
    "hbase.use.hbase.context",
    False,
).option(
    "hbase.config.resources",
    "file:///etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml",
).load()
```

This works fine and gives me the expected output :

```
df.show()

+--------+------------------+                                                   
|Campagne|                id|
+--------+------------------+
|   TEST1|100_TEST1_10000061|
|   TEST1| 100_TEST1_1000009|
|   TEST1|100_TEST1_10000824|
|   TEST1|100_TEST1_10000874|
|   TEST1|100_TEST1_10001248|
|   TEST1|100_TEST1_10001308|
...
```

The problem is that in the `data` column family, some of my qualifiers contain "space" in their name.
For example : `code_client INTEGER data:Code client`

I tried this (with error) :

```
columns_mapping = """
    id string :key,
    Campagne string data:Campagne,
    Code_client integer data:Code client
"""

spark.(...).load()  # using same command

> IllegalArgumentException: "Invalid value for hbase.columns.mapping '\n\tid string :key,\n\
tCampagne string data:Campagne,\n\tCode_client integer data:Code client\n'"
```

How can I add this columns in my `columns_mapping` to get the data with spark ? I guess I need some (back/double)quotes somewhere, but I cannot figure out where exactly.